# Xcode: How do I output a variable length array to the output window?

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, macos, swift3

I have a user interface that takes some parameters. Then, the user clicks the calculate button. At the end of that calculation, I write to a variable called `roots`. It will hold some number of `Double` values. I need to show these values on the same window where the user put in their parameters. How can I achieve this? New to Swift/Xcode/Mac in general.

The minimum I need to achieve is to just show the values of the array on that window. If I can make it pretty, that's a bonus.

Answer (score 0):

put a label (myLabel) in that view, connect it to your UIViewController of the case as an outlet, then in the action of the button:

```
myLabel.text = roots.description
```

Comment: This gives an error: `Value of type 'NSTextField' has no member 'text'`

Comment: use a UILabel object

Comment: It turns out that I had to do `myLabel.stringValue = roots.description`. Note that this is Swift3 and Mac (not iOS)